# Windows 8 freezes when killing "Metro" apps

Tags: windows-8, freeze, modern-ui, task-manager

Often after I use certain Windows 8 (formerly "Metro") apps, usually about a day later, I notice a marked drop in available RAM over what I was expecting.  Since I am running Virtual Machines that need the RAM, I go into Task Manager to reclaim it.  I inevitably find multiple Windows 8 apps there, all with Status "Suspended", claiming to be using hundreds of MB each.

The problem comes when I try to kill the processes of these applications.  Each time I click "End task", my computer freezes completely for up to 3-4 minutes.  This happens only when ending Windows 8 apps, not traditional apps.  I also can only reproduce it consistently when using Task Manager, but I cannot get it to freeze when I end a process using Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Note that this is **after** I have already "closed" the apps using one of the proper methods of closing a Windows 8 app - dragging to the bottom, right-clicking on the left-side thumbnail and choosing "Close", or using one of Win8 Update 1's new close buttons at the top of the screen or in the taskbar - it is already well-documented that apps do not close when you do those actions, instead going into "Suspended State".

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?  Have you been able to fix it?

---

(Occasionally, it also happens a day or so later that I suddenly hear the fan of my laptop spin up to high speed and see my remaining battery life dropping rapidly.  Looking in task manager, I see a `rundll32` process running `AEINV.DLL` with high CPU usage.  Killing that process slows the CPU fan and restores the battery life to its usual drain rate.  I have found references to the "Customer Experience Improvement Program" being the root cause of this, but I have that disabled on my computer.  This happens rarely enough that I'm not going to spend too much time on it, but I'm guessing it's related to my main problem here.)

Comment: Why are you end tasking the Metro applications instead of closing them by dragging them down?

Comment: @Ramhound I should have mentioned - this is usually about a day later *after I have "closed" them by dragging them down or by clicking 8.1 update 1's new "Close" button.  I have clarified the question.

Comment: I just tested trying to end task a metro process, I saw no ill effects, this seems to indicate a system integrity issue on your end.

Comment: the AEINV.DLL usage comes from the maintenance task which runs when Windows is idle. It scans your PC for installed software and sends this as telemetry to MS.